# How can I find a ranking for the answers?

Tags: support, answers, search, score

It is easy to find the questions with the best scores and the worst scores.

> But how can I find the answers with the best scores and the worst scores ? Is a ranking of the answers concerning the score available ?

Answer (score 4):

This can be done via the search bar.

[`is:answer`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aa) will let you search for only answers. Then you can sort by vote. You can even limit the results by [`is:answer score:100`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aa+score%3A100) to get only answers whose score is $\geq100$. This can be filtered even more by adding [`is:answer score:100 isaccepted:1`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aa+score%3A100+isaccepted%3A1) and focusing only on those answers which have been accepted, although your mileage may vary as far as "highest ranked" in that case.

Comment: Thank you, but apparently, it does not work for negative scores. What do I miss.

Comment: For negative score just take all answers, sort by votes, and go to the last page.

Comment: That does not work. I get a meesage that there are no matches.

Comment: Note that "lowest (most negative)" score for an answer means little, @Peter, save that for one reason or another, the answerer desired strongly to keep it, and/or other users failed to delete it.  Likely lower negative scores existed than currently exists, but were deleted, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Peter (and Asaf) The problem with going to the last page (sorted by score) is that this only works for limited number of pages. Meta Stack Exchange: [No more than 10,000 results are visible in search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303174).

Comment: @Peter You can give an upper bound for the score in the search, e.g. [is:answer score:..-5](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+score%3A..-5).

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you, solves my problem completely!

Answer (score 4):

[Data Explorer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) (SEDE) is useful for tasks like this. (With the warning that the data in SEDE are updated only once a week, so the most recent posts are not in the database. And also some posts might have gained a few more upvotes or downvotes since the database was last updated.)

You can try something like:

- [Answers with highest score](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/894366/answer-with-top-score)
- [Answers with lowest score](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/894367/answers-with-lowest-score)
- [Answers with highest score in a given tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/894371/answers-with-highest-score-in-a-given-tag?Tagname=algebra-precalculus)
- [Answers with lowest score in a given tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/894382/answers-with-lowest-score-in-a-given-tag?Tagname=algebra-precalculus)

---

I believe this answers the question satisfactorily. Still, I cannot resist to add a small remark. It is understandable that people might be interested in post with high score. (Since the upvotes the post gained means that many users saw there something worth upvoting.) On the other hand, it worth keeping in mind that looking only at such post might contribute to a kind of [Matthew effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_effect).

Comment: To be honest, I have the conversed intent. I want to look at questions with negative score to be able to vote to delete. Considering this , I do not understand the downvote. Are questions about the usage of this site off-topic ? And even if I had the intent to see the high-score answers , I do not understand what is bad with this question.

Comment: @Peter Well, that would be question mainly for the downvoter. (I have added paragraph about Matthew effect for users who see my answer in general, it was not aimed specifically you. I though it was worth mentioning, since many users do not want to concentrate on reputation and score too much. Of course, Matthew effect can work in the negative direction, too.)