# How to quickly find recent questions with lots of upvotes?

Tags: feature-request, search, up-votes, questions, score

Sometimes I want to find recent questions with lots of upvotes. My current way to do so is to go to Questions -> Newest, then do a lot of down-scrolling while visually scanning the numbers of votes. This is a bit slow. Is there a faster way to do this? For example, is there a way to list the questions asked in the last say 24 hours in descending score order?

Comment: I am not sure ([meta-tag:feature-request]) is actually a suitable tag here - since this thing already seems to exists, I'd say that ([meta-tag:support]) might be a better fit.

Comment: @MartinSleziak If there were a tag called "feature-request if it doesn't already exist", I would have chosen that. (Maybe I will request that feature - if it doesn't already exist.)

Comment: Just to clarify - neither of the options I've mentioned in my answer is *exactly* the same as your suggestion. (I.e., to get precisely the questions from the last 24 hours.) But still, I'd guess they're close enough. (I certainly wouldn't mind you unaccepting the answer - if you want to see whether somebody knows how to do exactly this.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The article "[How do I search?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching)" in the help center has a section "Dates" - which explains how to use dates with the operators `created:` and `lastactive:`.

If you want only questions, you can use `is:q`. Similarly, you can use `is:a` for answers.

As with any search, one of the options how to sort search results is by score.

For example, you can use searches such as:

- [created:1d is:q](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a1d+is:q) (This will return the questions from one day ago - i.e., from yesterday.)
- [created:1d.. is:q](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a1d..+is:q) - the questions created yesterday and later.
- And you can directly specify a date: [created:2022-07-23 is:q](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2022-07-23+is:q).
- You can use some date range: [created:2022-07-01..2022-08-01 is:q](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2022-07-01..2022-08-01+is:q)

Apart from ordering by score, you can use any sorting, but restrict the search to questions above a certain threshold. For example, you can search [for score:20](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a20) or [for score:10](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a10) and sort the search results to see the newest questions.

In addition to this [the users with 10k+ reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) can use questions and answers with the highest/lowest scores from today (or last 2/7/14/30 days) [in the moderator tools](https://math.stackexchange.com/tools).

There is also SEDE - where one can use SQL to create various queries. The table Posts contain both Score and Creationdate, so one can get top-voted questions within some date range. But since the database is updated once a week, this won't really work for the most recent. More detailed info about SEDE can be found [in the corresponding tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info). Here is an [example of a query along these lines](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1619931/top-questions-answers-between-two-dates?types=1&Date1=2022-06-01&Date2=2022-06-02) - you can modify date range and choice between questions/answers/both using the parameters of the query.

---

A similar question (feature request) on Meta Stack Exchange: [Search filter UI for recent posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352585).

Some related posts on this meta:

- [Ordering the questions of a day](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28170)
- [How can I find a ranking for the answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29051)
- [How can I search questions asked a specific period of time?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29402)
- [Searching for questions asked between two dates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19463)
- [How does one search for questions and answer by specific user and by date?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25386)
- [Access to question posts from previous years.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28512)
- [How does one search for questions and answer by specific user and by date?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25386)

Comment: Now I see that this is more-or-less a duplicate of: [Ordering the questions of a day](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28170). But when I posted an answer there, I did not know about possibility of using stuff such as `1d`, `1m`, `1y` in the operator `created:`.